# Working with "..." input in R function

Tags: r, function, input, user-input, tapply

I am putting together an R function that takes some undefined input through the `...` argument described in the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Functions) as:

> "..."  the special variable length argument ***

The idea is that the user will enter a number of column names here, each belonging to a dataset also specified by the user. These columns will then be cross-tabulated in comparison to the dependent variable by `tapply`. The function is to return a table (independent variable x indedependent variable).

Thus, I tried:

```
plotter=function(dataset, dependent_variable,  ...) 

{


indi_variables=list(...); # making a list of the ... input as described in the docs
result=with (dataset, tapply(dependent_variable, indi_variables, mean); # this fails

}
```

I figured this should work as [tapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tapply.html) can take a list as input. 
But it does not in this case (*'Error in tapply...arguments must have same length'*) and I think it is because `indi_variables` is a list of strings. 
If I input the contents of the list by hand and leave out the quotation marks, everything works just fine.

However, if the user feeds the function the column names as non-strings, R will interpret them as variable names; and I cannot figure out how to transform the list `indi_variables` in the right way, unsuccessfully trying things like this:

```
indi_variables=lapply(indi_variables, as.factor)
```

So I am wondering

- What causes the error described above? Is my interpretation correct?
- How would one go about transforming the list created through `...` in the right way?
- Is there an overall better way of doing this, in the input or the implementation of `tapply`?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You should probably read [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) section of Hadley's book (read it slowly and several times, it's a difficult topic).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joran's helpful reading, I have come up with these improvements than make things work out...

```
indi_variables=substitute(list(...));

result=with (dataset, tapply(dependent_variable, eval(indi_variables, dataset), FUN=mean));
```